# Fullscreen Google map in bootstrap 4 large modal not show

Tags: javascript, google-maps, bootstrap-4

I add a google map in a large modal using bootstrap 4.
when modal show, Map is work but when i click fullscreen button, the modal and map not display just blank. My head was broken thinking this. How to fix it?

Before:
[image: before]
<sub>(source: [image.ibb.co](https://image.ibb.co/cWhi2c/beforex.png))</sub>

After:
[image: after]

My javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var marker, i;
var markers=[];
function load_map(){
  if (typeof google === 'object' && typeof google.maps === 'object') {

    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(<?=$row->lat?>,<?=$row->lon?>);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 20,
      center: myLatLng,
      fullscreenControl: true,
      scaleControl:true,
      streetViewControl:true,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    //set markers
    var locations=<?=json_encode($kordinat)?>;
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon: {
          url:base_url+'assets/base/images/marker_black.png'
        }
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }
    //target marker
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map
    });
    markers.push(marker);

    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers,{imagePath: base_url+'assets/base/images/m'});
    map.setCenter(myLatLng);

  }else{
  $('#show-map').slideDown();
  $('#map').slideUp();
     alert('Tidak dapat memuat peta ! Periksa koneksi internet !');
  }
}

$('#show-map').click(function(){
    $(this).slideUp();
    $('#map').slideDown();
    setTimeout(function(){load_map()}, 1000);
});});
```

My HTML code:

```
<div class="modal fade modal-3d-slit show" id="modal-detail" aria-labelledby="exampleModalPrimary" role="dialog" tabindex="-1"><div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
      <div class="ribbon ribbon-corner ribbon-info ribbon-reverse">
        <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal">
          <span class="ribbon-inner"><i class="icon md-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <h4 class="modal-title"><span class="icon md-account-circle"</span>Detail Izin</h4>
    </div>
  <div class="modal-body"><style type="text/css">li.list-group-item:hover{background: #eeeeee}</style>
    <div class="nav-tabs-animate nav-tabs-inverse nav-tabs-horizontal" data-plugin="tabs"><ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-pemohon" aria-expanded="false">Pemohon</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-izin" aria-expanded="true">Izin</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-persyaratan" aria-expanded="false">Persyaratan</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-tindakan" aria-expanded="false">Riwayat Tindakan</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane animation-scale-up mt-10 active" id="tab-izin" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true">
              <table class="table table-hover"></table>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-classic btn-block btn-lg" id="show-map"><i class="icon md-map"></i> Tampilkan Peta</button>

              <div id="map" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>

          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are saying that when you _click_ the full screen button both map and modal go blank; what error do you get in the console?

Comment: no error on console. Now i found, if i move the map outiside on tab content it work. But my client won't it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar (not a Google Map, but Esri's JS-mapping library) with Bootstrap - have the map in a modal, but take up as much real estate as possible. I know that JS maps are really finicky - you have to have some way for the browser to set at least one dimension in pixels unless you're going 100% for both dimensions. (At least, that's the way it used to be when I first started with JS Maps.) I suspect that might be what's happening but I'm also guessing when you click full screen, the map no longer knows it's supposed to be inside that modal content.

Anyway, I'm using an iframe (id="mapiFrame") within the modal-body div, and the following CSS gets me *really close* to what I want:

```
#mapiFrame {
  height: calc(80vh - 5px);
  width: calc(90vw - 5px);
}

.modal-dialog {
  max-width: none;
  max-height: none;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: It seems to work for all but the truly weirdest viewport sizes. But I'd love to know if anyone has a better solution!